# How can i add new column from sql statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, union

i want to make my sql result from this:

```
      |    Sum    |
      -------------
      | 2343554665|
      |    4545786|
```

into like that:

```
    Key     |    Sum    |
--------------------------
flash disk  | 2343554665|
mouse       |    4545786|
```

i want to write manually the in the column Key... because there isn't name of the Key.

this is my code

```
INSERT Key into orders_1 values 'Flash disk'
SELECT SUM(quantity)as sum FROM orders_1
UNION ALL
INSERT Key into orders_1 values 'mouse'
SELECT SUM(quantity*priceEach) FROM orders_1;
```

i got error

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server; what RDBMS are you *really* using?  "i got error" doesn't tell us anything either; what was the error? `UNION ALL` to an `INSERT` statement doesn't make any sense either; `INSERT` doesn't return a dataset, it **inserts** one. If you need to return a dataset from an `INSERT` statement, you need to use `OUTPUT`, however, you can't use that in conjuction with a `UNION ALL`. What you are trying to do here is very unclear.

Comment: Do you want to update or insert? And in which table?

Comment: Inserting into the same table you're selectting from makes little sense as well; especially inserting an aggregated value into it. You would better off with a `VIEW` if you want aggregated values.

Comment: hi, all. actually i want to adding new column with the name 'Key' and the values is 'flash disk' from the sum of quantity column. and then the result sum of quantity times priceEach column create name 'mouse'

Comment: Then why are you inserting? You aren't making any sense here. And we still need to know what RDBMS you are *really* using.

Comment: i use my sql, bro

Comment: Then retag MySQL in your question, @uud , as I removed the tags as SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. I am, however, not your brother; if you were, you would have called me with a SQL question. ;)

Comment: Why you want to call the total quantity 'Flash disk' and the total price 'mouse' is beyond me. And I don't think you really want to insert something into your table. You merely seem to want `select 'Flash disk' as key, sum(quantity) ... union all select 'mouse' as key, sum(quantity*priceeach) ... `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in my comment assuming that you do not want to insert your manually created key column and sum values into the same table orders_1; you should consider union all first then insert the result.

```
INSERT into orders_1_example --assuming this is not the table you want to insert your new values so i changed its name
SELECT 'Flash disk',SUM(quantity)as sum FROM orders_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'mouse', SUM(quantity*priceEach) FROM orders_1;
```

Edit: You should create a new table named after it `orders_1_example` with two columns (key,sum) then insert it like this. If there is no column named 'key' in tour table of cource you can not insert it. If you want to insert `orders_1` table then you should alter your table to add a new column then insert with this way.

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS_1 ADD COLUMN KEY VARCHAR2(50);

INSERT into orders_1 (KEY,SUM)
SELECT 'Flash disk',SUM(quantity)as sum FROM orders_1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'mouse', SUM(quantity*priceEach) FROM orders_1;
```

Then again doing this is pointless.

Comment: there are no name of 'flask disk' and 'mouse' i have to write manually to add in data base.

Comment: Edited my answer check it. @uud